# syntax function into Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a module which written into notepad:

```
-module(hhfuns).
-compile(export_all).

one() -> 1.
two() -> 2.
add(X,Y) - X() + Y().
```

and I save it as hhfuns.erl. When I run Ok then I called:

```
hhfuns:add(myfun hhfun:one/0, myfun hhfun:two/0).
```

this command make syntax error. But when I changed **myfun** to **fun** it worked.maybe it's a basic syntax but I'm new at Erlang, so please explain for me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing function from outside module as a parameter you should use syntax `fun Module:Function/Arity`. Correct version for you will be `hhfuns:add(fun hhfun:one/0, fun hhfun:two/0)`. `fun` here is a required keyword and you can not use `myfun` here instead.

Comment: `fun hhfuns:one/0, fun hhfuns:two/0`, actually.

Comment: Useful to note that there is nothing special about the function being in or out of the module. Within the module `fun funcname/0` also works; every so often you may see `start() -> spawn_link(fun init/0)` in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

In fact `myfun` is not an Erlang keyword, whereas `fun` is.